# Does "**societies**" here mean "groups of people" or "registered organizations"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

This page [says](https://www.acm.org/education/curricula-recommendations)

> In the decades since the 1960s, ACM, along with leading professional and scientific computing **societies**, has endeavored to tailor curriculum recommendations to the rapidly changing landscape of computer technology. As the computing field continues to evolve, and new computing-related disciplines emerge, existing curriculum reports will be updated, and additional reports for new computing disciplines will be drafted.

Does "**societies**" here mean "groups of people" or "registered organizations"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, *societies* mean organizations with similar interest and profession.

> *ACM and leading professional and scientific computing societies (organizations or firms sharing similar profession or interest) has endeavoured...*

More such usages are here [on Collins.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/society)